# Verificando commit PDO

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

preciso dar msg de salvo com sucesso só quando o COMMIT for executado sem.

o problema está no retorno do ajax, no done.

no meu HTML quando acontece algum erro, ele retorna o erro do catch e ok do commit

preciso printar o OK só se o arquivo for incluido com sucesso sem erro algum, pelo que vi ele existe o commit mas ele não foi executado pois meu retorno está assim.

"Error: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of
 tokens""ok"

essa mensagem nem entra no DONE do ajax. Esse é o problema, assim não aparece nenhuma msg para o usuario, a mensagem só fica no console.log.

meu ajax.

```
function sub(arquivo, acao) {
    $("#load").show();
    var Self = this;

    if (Self.working) {
        return;
    }
    Self.working = true;

    var formData = new FormData($("#form")[0]);
    formData.append("acao", acao);
    formData.append("arquivo", arquivo);

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
        url: 'model/acao/controller.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    }).done(function (html) {
        if (html == "ok") {
            if (acao == 'Incluir') {
                alert("Salvo com sucesso");
            }
            if (acao == 'Alterar') {
                alert("Alterado com Sucesso");
            }
        } else {

            alert(html);
        }
    }).complete(function () {
        Self.working = false;
        $("#load").hide();
    });

}
```

meu commit

```
   public function commit() {
            if (DB::getInstance()->commit()) {
                print json_encode("ok");
            }
        }
```

meu arquivo crud está com o incluir assim.

```
public function insert($table, array $dados, $bool = true) {
        try {
            if ($bool == true) {

                $this->beginTransaction();
            }
            $sql = "INSERT INTO $table ({$this->colunas($table)->select}) VALUES ({$this->colunas($table)->indiceInsert})";
            $stmt = DB::prepare($sql);
            foreach ($dados as $key => $v) {
                $stmt->bindValue(':' . $key, $v);
            }
//            print'<pre>';
//            $stmt->debugDumpParams();
//            print'</pre>';
            if ($stmt->execute()) {
                $cd = DB::getInstance()->lastInsertId();
                return $cd;
            } else {
                echo json_encode("Erro ao Inserir!");
                return false;
            }
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo json_encode('Error: ' . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Meu incluir

```
public function incluir() {
        $dados = $this->dados();
        $dados['dt_boletim'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

        if (self::insert($this->table, $dados)) {
            self::commit();
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Muita calma nessa hora, seu php sempre envia um json e no javascript vc sempre compara uma string, precisa transformar ela em um json e comparar os valores corretamente.

Comment: @rray Tem como fazer um exemplo?

Comment: É algo mais ou menos assim, `var res = JSON.parse(html); if(res.ok){ alert('insert ok'); }` na dúvida da um `console.log(res)`. Prefira ser consistante, por exemplo sempre mande no json um atributo chamado `msg` o valor dele pode ser um erro ou sucesso, pq no caso de erro o `ok` não vai existir ai vc tem dois problemas ;)

Comment: Quando ao `Invalid parameter number` vc sabe resolver?

Comment: @rray Estou tentando resolver mas não obtive sucesso.

Comment: `Invalid parameter number` acontece quando vc tem um valor a mais que uma coluna ou um placeholder a mais ou a menos. Imprimir a sql ajuda a detectar onde está a falha.

Comment: Já resolvi a parte do sql vlw.

Comment: @rray o problema é que não entra no done ele cai direto no fail  retorno do log ({"erro":"Error: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number
 of tokens"}{"success":"ok"}) estou deixando o erro só para tentar mostrar a msg na tela do usuario.

Comment: Não tem `.fail()` na pergunta, vc fez o JSON.parse()?